# How to remove carriage return characters from string as if it was printed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, stdout, carriage-return

I would like to remove all occurrences of `\r` from a string as if it was printed via `print()` and store the result in another variable.

Example:

```py
>>> s = "hello\rworld"
>>> print(s)
world
```

In this example, how do I "print" `s` to a new variable which then contains the string `"world"`?

Background:
I am using the subprocess module to capture the stdout which contains a lot of `\r` characters. In order to effectively analyze the string I would like to only have the resulting output.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my answer. Apparently, I misinterpreted the test I did before answering. It doesn't actually work.

Comment: The result will also depend on the width (in characters) of the terminal. If "hello" is replaced by something longer than this width, "world" is printed on the next line.

Comment: The first ways that came to mind don't work. You may need to "emulate" it by doing something like splitting on returns and then taking the last result.

Comment: What's the correct result for `"carriage\rm"`? (Reminds me of a song I like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex:

```
import re

s = "hello\rworld"
out = re.sub(r'([^\r]+)\r([^\r\n]+)',
             lambda m: m.group(2)+m.group(1)[len(m.group(2)):],
             s)
```

Output: `'world'`

More complex example:

```
import re

s = "hello\r..\nworld"

out = re.sub(r'([^\r]+)\r([^\r\n]+)',
             lambda m: m.group(2)+m.group(1)[len(m.group(2)):],
             s)
```

Output:

```
..llo
world
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually just now looked at your answer, someone else must have downvoted it... The idea of using `re.sub()` is great, however, for my use case a much simpler regex is sufficient: `re.sub(r".*\r", "", s)`.

Comment: @trivicious yes this was my original answer which I then updated to add more edge cases ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess one very simple way to get the same result would be to split the string on every occurrence of the carriage return (`\r`) and then return only the last result.

```py
>>> s = "hello\rworld"
>>> res = s.split("\r")[-1]
>>> res
'world'
```

Comment: This wouldn't work on `s = "hello\rworld\nhello\ragain"`

Comment: Yeah sure, hence why I called it a very simple solution to achieve the very same result for the input as provided within the question (which was only about carriage returns). It will not handle any other cases like \n or \t within the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```py
import re
s = "Example\n of\r text \r\nwith \\r!"
s2 = re.sub("\r\n", "\n", s)
s2 = re.sub("[^\n]*\r", "", s2)
print(s)
print(s2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the idea of using `re.sub()` is great, however, for my use case a much simpler regex is sufficient: `re.sub(r".*\r", "", s)`. Note that your print statements should be `print(repr(s))` as using `print()` alone does "interpret" the `\r` again.

Comment: The idea was to show that the print results were the same even when the `\r` was removed. I noticed that @mozway was giving a more complete answer so I left it as is. Good that you found a more elegant solution to your problem in the end.